# Attribute Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'thumbnails': python-django

Tags: python, django, attributeerror

I'm rendering an image in a template like this:

```
{% if feature.photo %}
{% render_photo feature.photo_inverted "Product large" class="img-responsive img-full" %}
{% endif %}
```

Where feature is an instance of a product object from a product model. Sometimes it gives an

```
Attribute: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'thumbnails': python-django
```

when I attempt to load the templates and sometimes the template loads successfully with the image rendered. Any ideas on how to fix this?

**EDIT**
The method I use is a template tag that looks like so:

```
def render_photo(photo, size_name, *args, **kwargs):
    """Renders the HTML markup for the given photo.

    If the given size does not exist, the photo is displayed in its
    original size. If the size does exist, but there is no thumbnail of
    that size, the original image is used and displayed at the desired size.

    """
    html = '<img src="{0}{1}" alt="{2}" width="{3}" height="{4}" {5}/>'
    attrs = ''
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        if len(attrs) > 0: attrs += ' '
        attrs += '{0}="{1}"'.format(key, value)
    try:
        thumbnail = photo.thumbnails.get(size__name=size_name)
        return html.format(project_settings.MEDIA_URL, thumbnail.image,
                           thumbnail.title, thumbnail.size.width,
                           thumbnail.size.height, attrs)
    except Photo.DoesNotExist: # There is no thumbnail of the given size
        try:
            size = Size.objects.get(name=size_name)
            width, height = size.width, size.height
        except Size.DoesNotExist: # The given size does not exist
            dimensions = settings.SIZES.get(size_name)
            if dimensions:
                # The size is defined in the settings
                width, height = dimensions
                Size.objects.create(name=size_name, width=width, height=height)
            else:
                width, height = photo.width, photo.height
        return html.format(project_settings.MEDIA_URL, photo.image, photo.title,
                           width, height, attrs)
```

Comment: Your sure feature.photo exists in both cases?

Comment: Yes I am sure they exist. If they didn't it wouldn't go through the if template, and the pictures render sometimes without giving any errors which is why I am so confused.

Comment: Maybe the rendering part is more clear. But you got this error on same pict (like once ok/once error) or it may be related to progressive jpeg/thumbnail in metadata? Post the function that do the job, it is useful to see where the error pop from

Comment: @cox I have edited the post to include the method I use.

Comment: But your condition is if feature.photo, but render gets feature.photo_inverted. Why not feature.photo_inverted in conditional check?